# Ignore no new error for abstract classe

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract class that in one of its functions needs to create an instance of its self. Obviously in the inherited classes `new this()` will create a new instance of the inherited class not the abstract class.

Typescript errors at `new this()` because technically I am creating a new instance of the abstract class (or would be if I used the class directly).

Is it possible to ignore the error? I'd prefer to ignore only that line not all news on abstract classes.

Removing `abstract` from the class definition makes typescript happy and the code works as intended. So the only issue here is that typescript isn't happy.

Comment: If you need to instantiate it, then it's not an abstract class, right? That's pretty much the definition of abstract. So, why do you feel it's appropriate to declare it as abstract if you need a new instance of it?

Comment: I never make an instance of the abstract class. only the ones that inherit from it. If I have to declare any functions that need to create a new instance of the class on all of the inherited classes it kind of defeats the object of using an inherited class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *getPrototypeOf*

```
abstract class Parent {
    replicate(): this {
        return new (Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor)();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {}

let c = (new Child).replicate();

console.log(c); // Child {}
```