# typescript ignore cannot instantiate abstract class error

Tags: typescript

The TS compiler complains that I cannot instantiate MeteorCollection at the line `return new this`

```
abstract class MeteorCollection {
    static $collection: Collection<any>

    static findOne(selector: Selector = {}, options: FindOneOptions = {}) {
        let item = this.$collection.findOne(selector, options)
        return new this(item)
    }
}
```

How can I tell it that it is ok, since this refers to the constructor of a class that will extend MeteorCollection and not to MeteorCollection itself.

Comment: you could use the //@ts-ignore comment above the line with the error or try the approach used in this previous answer -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423152/ignore-no-new-error-for-abstract-classe/47425738#47425738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to ignore the error. I assume you intend to invoke the method from a reference to a subclass so use a `this` type annotation.

```
abstract class MeteorCollection {
  static $collection: Collection<any>;

  static findOne<T extends MeteorCollection>(
    this: typeof MeteorCollection & (new (arg: any, ...args: any[]) => T),
    selector: Selector = {},
    options: FindOneOptions = {}
  ) {
    const item = this.$collection.findOne(selector, options);
    return new this(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: It solved the initial problem, but now it complains that property $collection does not exist on new(...args: any[])

Comment: Almost there... Now it says that it expects 0 arguments for new this

Comment: @Chris I found a better way to write it that is more maintainable and DRY. Take a look.